# Laravel DB Query with multiple sub strings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am looking to run a a DB query where if a user queries with multiple sub-strings across two columns they can bey queried.  For example,

Column 1 is Country Name and Column 2 is City and Country Name. Sample data:

```
Column1| Column2
USA | Portland, Oregon, United States of America
USA | Portland, Maine, United State of America
USA | Bellevue, Washington, United State of America
USA | Bellevue, Nebraska, United State of America
```

Now user can query using various option.  For example:

```
Portland America 
Portland USA
Portland Oregon USA
Portland Oregon America
Portland United States
... and so on
```

I am looking to build a query that can solve this for me. I tried the combination of where and orwhere but that didn't solve for it.

To elaborate further, the country name in column one can also be Republic of China.  And the query can be random combination of either two words or strings from the same column or column1 and column2 combined.  Or it can be just a single word.

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, you'll want to break up the string and search each part.

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(function($query) use ($string) {
     $parts = explode(' ', $string);
     foreach($parts as $part) {
          $query->where('Column2', 'LIKE', "%$part%")
     }
})->get();
```

This will turn the query into something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name 
     WHERE Column2 LIKE '%Portland%' 
     AND Column2 LIKE '%America%'
```

To also check against Column1, add another where clause, but this time use the Or:

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(function($query) use ($string) {
     $parts = explode(' ', $string);
     foreach($parts as $part) {
          $query->where('Column2', 'LIKE', "%$part%")
     }
})->where(function($query) use ($string) {
     $parts = explode(' ', $string);
     foreach($parts as $part) {
          $query->orWhere('Column1', 'LIKE', "%$part%")
     }
})->get();
```

This changed the query to be

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name 
     WHERE (Column2 LIKE '%Portland%' 
        AND Column2 LIKE '%USA%')
     AND (Column1 LIKE '%Portland%' OR Column1 LIKE '%USA%')
```

This is fine if they search for `USA`, but not if they search for `United States`. You may need to refine the search parameters a bit more, or add a way to match abbreviations to country names.

Comment: Thanks.   What if lets say there are 100 recurrences of portland in Column 2.  And the user searches for Portland USA.  Means Portland from Coulum2 and USA from Column 1.  Essentially I am trying to figure out a a way to capture the user intent.

Comment: You can add a separate orWhere clause ... I'll edit the answer with that.

Comment: Is the second where is supposed to be orWhere?  Because your mentioned in your comments but the code doesn't show that.

Comment: No, it becomes `where (a and b and c) and (d or e or f)`. From what it sounds like, you want the country to match but it's a single acronym, so that becomes an `OR`. If you had `(a and b and c) or (d or e or f)`, then it would match USA or Portland `(Column2 LIKE '%Portland%' AND Column2 LIKE '%USA%') and (Column1 LIKE '%Portland%' OR Column1 LIKE '%USA%')`, which wouldn't narrow down your choices.

Comment: The problem comes in when someone searches for `Portland United States`, and there's nothing to match Column1 `(Column2 LIKE '%Portland%' AND Column2 LIKE '%United%' AND Column2 LIKE '%States%') and (Column1 LIKE '%Portland%' OR Column1 LIKE '%United%' OR Column1 LIKE '%States%')` - no matches.

Comment: Ok.  A couple of things one I had to remove the white space by using preg_split.  Second your $query->orWhere('Column1', 'LIKE', "%$part%") needs to be closed with a semi colon.  Third if someone types Portland only it returns no results. Therefore  you have to use orWhere before the second function.  Four lets say there is a country called Republic of China in Column 1 and City called Shanghai Shandong China  and you query for Shanghai Republic of China or Republic of China Shanghai or Republic Shanghai the query returns as empty.   If I type Republic of China i should get list of all cities

Comment: May be the detail i am missing in my question is that it can be a random combination of any two strings either from the same column or column 1 and column 2.

Comment: Sorry about the typos. That's what happens when I write it out here instead of an IDE. Maybe you need to search the combined columns instead of individually. The easiest way is to use one where/foreach loop, and do `$query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(Column1, ' ', Column2)"), 'LIKE', "%$part%");`  This will search for the individual words anywhere in the string `USA Portland, Oregon, United States of America`.

Comment: SELECT *, MATCH (column1, coulmn2) AGAINST ('Republic of China Shanghai') AS score FROM table WHERE MATCH (column1, coulmn2) AGAINST ('Republic of China Shanghai') ; worked where column1 had Republic of China and column2 had shanghai.  However I cannot run this in laravel as raw query.

Comment: Please see my answer below. That worked.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

DB::select( DB::raw(SELECT *, MATCH (column1, coulmn2) AGAINST ('Republic of China Shanghai') AS score FROM table WHERE MATCH (column1, coulmn2) AGAINST ('Republic of China Shanghai')));  provides the answer I was looking for.  It essentially uses FULLTEXT SEARCh across both columns.